# bilinear maps rules

Tags: group-theory

A bilinear map has to satisfy this property:

$e(aP,bQ) = e(P,Q)^{ab}$ for all $P,Q \in \mathbb{G} , a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_q$

so far so good.

My question now is related to this paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/080.pdf

Under "4.1 Correctness" they do the following changes (I replaced some complex constructs with c, d and simplified it a little bit):

(1) $e(g_2^a \cdot c^d,g)=e(g_2,g)^a \cdot e(c,g)^d$

(2) $e(g_2,g)^a \cdot e(c,g)^d=e(g_2,g^a) \cdot e(c,g^d)$

And there is another change I saw somewhere else:

(3) $e(g_1, g_2) = e(g_2, g_1)$

So, for me it looks like I can pull down the exponent of a bilinear map $e$ to one of the arguments of $e$ (2). And that I can split one bilinear map $e$ into two bilinear maps in the way described in (1). Is this true in all scenarios? I assume this is not the case. I assume this is only possible in $\mathbb{Z}_q$. Or maybe only with generators? ... I am only guessing.

So these are my questions:

- Under which conditions are (1), (2) and (3) valid changes?
- Why are (1), (2) and (3) valid changes? I assume this is related to the bilinearity property mentioned above.

Regards,
hyperion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1), (2), and (3) are always valid changes as long as $\mathbb{G}$ is a cyclic group.

Note that you switched from additive notations at the beginning of your post to multiplicative notations later; I'll stick to multiplicative notations in my answer. Now, let me show that a bilinear map satisfying $e(g^a,h^b) = e(g,h)^{ab}$ for all $(g,h)\in\mathbb{G}$ and $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}_q$ will necessarily satisfy (1), (2), and (3). Let me denote (0) the first equation (that defines a bilinear map).

Everything follows relatively easily from the following observation: as $\mathbb{G}$ is a cyclic group, every element of $\mathbb{G}$ (except $1_{\mathbb{G}}$) is a generator: given $(g,h)\in\mathbb{G}$, you can always find $x\in\mathbb{Z}_q$ such that $h = g^x$. Therefore:

(1) Let me denote $(x_2,x_c)\in\mathbb{Z}_q^2$ two exponents such that $g_2=g^{x_2}$ and $c = g^{x_c}$. We get:

$e(g_2^a\cdot c^d,g) = e(g^{ax_2+x_cd},g)$ by writing $(g_2,c)$ "in base $g$"

$= e(g,g)^{ax_2+x_cd}$ by (0)

$= e(g,g)^{ax_2}\cdot e(g,g)^{x_cd}$

$= e(g^{ax_2},g)\cdot e(g,g^{x_cd})$ by applying (0) to the left and right terms

$= e(g_2^a,g)\cdot e(g,c^d)$

(2) The equality $e(g_2,g)^a \cdot e(c,g)^d=e(g_2,g^a) \cdot e(c,g^d)$ directly follows by applying (0) to the left and right terms, e.g. $e(g_2,g^a) = e(g_2^1,g^a) = e(g_2,g)^{a\cdot 1} = e(g_2,g)^a$.

(3) By now you should probably be able to deal with this one yourself: fix any base $g$, let $g_1 = g^{x_1}$ for some $x_1$ and $g_2 = g^{x_2}$ for some $x_2$. Then $e(g_1,g_2) = e(g^{x_1},g^{x_2}) = e(g,g)^{x_1x_2} = e(g,g)^{x_2x_1} = e(g^{x_2},g^{x_1}) = e(g_2,g_1)$, simply by applying (0) twice.

Comment: Hi, "Let me denote $(x_2,x_c) \in Z_q^2$" - is the 2 by intention?

Comment: Yes, to make it more clear that those are exponents in base $g $ for $(g_2,g_c)$.